# how to animate transition from one view to another when using data templates to associate view with view-model

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm, mvvm-light, transition

i will post my source code i have at the moment and explain my problem after that.

this is the window where i want the transition to happen

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MyApp" Height="600" Width="800">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="View1" Command="{Binding View1Command}"/>
    <Button COntent="View2" Command="{Binding View2Command}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyContent}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This is the associated View-Model

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand View1Command{ get; private set;}
    public RelayCommand View2Command{ get; private set;}

    //INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented of course
    public ViewModelBase MyContent { get; set;}

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        View1Command = new RelayCommand(() => { MyContent = new ViewModel1();});
        View2Command = new RelayCommand(() => { MyContent = new ViewModel2();});
    }
}
```

In the app.xaml i used a data template to associate ViewModel1 with View1 and ViewModel2 with View2. That all works as expected. When clicking the buttons, the view changes, databinding works and everything is ok.

What i like to do now is to use an animation when the view changes.

what do i have to do to animate the transition between the two views with let's say a fade in animation for the new view. the old view disappears and the new one is faded in within one second.

hope you can help me.

best regards

pascal

p.s. if my approach with the data template does not make sense and animation is impossible with that approach i am open for other best practices to change from onw view to another. the solution i use is taken from the wpf demo app by karl shifflet, but i have no idea if that's the right solution for the thing i try to do.

Comment: Do not have enough time to write a full answer so here is a quick summary: the key point is to use transitions from [BoT](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) library (sample file can be found [here](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot/blob/master/Demo/Wpf/TransitionPresenter/TransitionPresenterPage.xaml) ). Take a look at `TransitionPresenter` control, it has `Content` property so all you have to do is to select a fade in transition and bind `Content` to your `MyContent` VM property. Of course I haven't tried doing that but it doesn't seem to be difficult.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i changed my approach for the transition by using the view model locator for binding view to viewmodel and the visual state manager for transition.

Comment: Mind posting the guts of your solution?  I'm working on something similar and struggling to maintain MVVM while eliciting the behavior I want.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Window.Resources>
<Storyboard x:Key="OnClick1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CC1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CC2">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnClick2">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CC1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CC2">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>       
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="button">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnClick1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnClick1}"/>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnClick2_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnClick2}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <StackPanel> 
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="View1" Command="{Binding View1Command}"/>  
            <Button Content="View2" Command="{Binding View2Command}"/> 
            <Grid>
                <ContentControl Name="CC1" Opacity="1" Content="{Binding MyContent}"/> 
                <ContentControl Name="CC2" Opacity="0" Content="{Binding MyContent}"/> 
            </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: and this makes a rubbish out of MVVM

Comment: Ugly. What if you have 10 views, do you maintain 10 ContentControls like this in memory?